# How do I get the appointment status in EWS Java API?

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I am using the [EWS Java API 1.2](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi) and now I need to expand my program to know if an appointment has a certain status (available, busy, out of office). How can I know this? Looking through to [documentation of the appointment class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) did not bring anything at first sight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method to get this info is called `getLegacyFreeBusyStatus()`. This returns an enum called `LegacyFreeBusyStatus` with the values `Free`, `Tentative`, `Busy`, `OOF` or `NoData`. (OOF being Out Of Office)

Comment: OOF == Out Of Facility ~= Out of Office :)